# What exactly is a distinguished point in the Riemann sum when defining the definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

[image]

I do not understand what a distinguished point is. Is it a real number between endpoints $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i}$, or something else?

(source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Formalization)

Comment: Yes, it can be any real number between $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$.

Comment: It's just a choice of point in the interval that has been given a special name.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Is it different for every $i$, or it stays constant ? By that I mean the distance from $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i}$ to the distinguished point

Comment: @BiliDebili It's chosen arbitrarily. One can prove that the resulting integral is independent of the choice of distinguished points.

Comment: @BiliDebili - you should look up the Darboux integral - it is a clearer and equivalent version of the Riemann integral that doesn't require things like tagged partitions.

Comment: @rubikscube09 I will take a look

Comment: @AlexProvost So basically it could also be a negative value right ?

Comment: Part of the point is that you can choose any point in the interval as the tag. So there are more "tagged partitions" than partitions. And when you take sup/inf over all tagged partitions you are dealing with a richer set of possibilities.

Comment: @MarkBennet So let's say if we would want to compute a random function by the definition of integral, then this "distinguished point" would be the problem to choose the correct one, if I am not mistaking, right ?

Comment: By taking sup/inf you make the choice of specific points irrelevant - each possible choice is taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

There are various constructions of the definite Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)\>dx$. All of them work with *partitions*
$${\cal P}:\quad a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_N=b$$
of the interval $[a,b]$, and some of them work with *tagged* partitions $({\cal P}, {\bf t})$  (or similarly notated), where in addition to the separating points $x_i$ of ${\cal P}$ we choose in each interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ $\>(1\leq i\leq N)$  an "evaluating point" $t_i$. These points $t_i$ are in no way "distinguished". The $t_i$ are just $N$ more "dummy variables" entering in the limiting process.

The result of this limiting process is always the same, and is denoted by $\int_a^b f(x)\>dx$. When we just have partitions ${\cal P}$ we need additional "local infs and sups" to form lower and upper Riemann sums (i.e., "hidden limits")
$$L(f,{\cal P}):=\sum_{i=1}^N \inf\bigl\{f(t)\bigm|x_{i-1}\leq t\leq x_i\bigr\}\>(x_i-x_{i-1}),\qquad U(f,{\cal P}):=\ldots\ .$$
With tagged partitions we just look at sums
$$R(f,{\cal P}):=\sum_{i=1}^N f(t_i)\>(x_i-x_{i-1})\ ,$$
whereby the $t_i$-data are tacitly assumed, but not referred to in the $R$-notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the left-hand sum, right-hand sum, trapezoidal sum, etc. Those are ways of choosing your distinguished points and partitions. The integral exists when you are allowed to choose *any* distinguished point for *any* partition and take the limit as the length of your partitions goes to zero.

[image]
[image]